# java smartCard I/O secure channel

Tags: java, smartcard

I currently try to wrote test about a JavaCard applet. I'm using JUnit and javax.smartcardio to send all my commands to the smartCard. 
But i need to open a secure channel to get one of my test running properly.
After two day of hard reasarch on the documentation and experiment I can't find a way to open this secure channel. do anyone have a clue with the smartcardio API ? or an other API willing to do that ?

```
//TODO: need secure channel
    byte[] header = {(byte)0x02, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x01}; //tag + length
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(header);
    outputStream.write(Value.SN.getBytes());
    byte[] excpectedRes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    // not a secure channel at all
    ResponseAPDU answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x84, 0xCA, 0x02, 0x01, Value.Emptydata));
    nameTest = "Test Select Serial number " + answer.toString();
    CheckSW(0x90, 00, answer);
    CheckResult(excpectedRes, result);
```

This is my code and i always get a 0x69 0x82 answer (Security status not satisfied)

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate your question or post your non working code...explain where is the problem

Comment: @AnuragSharma code exemple done.
the probeleme is my channel is a simple javax.smartcardio.CardChannel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to send `Get Data` command which requires authentication which means you should run `initialize update` and `external authenticate` before using Get data command.

If you just want to test your code working or not you can test with selecting MF, and the APDU is
`A0 A4 00 00 02 3F00` which will return `9F XX`.

Comment: @user2194553 have you verified this?

Comment: Yeah but it's send me back a 6A 86
I'm now send my research on this http://secinfo.msi.unilim.fr/opal/
Librairie thats seems do what i want